# JPA GenerationType.AUTO not considering column with auto increment

Tags: java, sql-server, database, hibernate, jpa

I have a table with a simple int id column with Identity auto increment in SQL Server.

The entity's Id is annotated with `@Id` and `@GeneratedValue`

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id", length = 4, precision = 10, nullable = false)
private Integer id;
```

In SQL Server the column is properly set as Identity with `Seed` and `Increment` equals to 1.

When I try to persist an instance of this entity, Hibernate tries to query the hibernate_sequence table to obtain the ID value. Since I haven't created that table in my schema I'm getting an error:

`could not read a hi value: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'MySchema.hibernate_sequence'`

If I change the generation type to IDENTITY everything works as expected

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", length = 4, precision = 10, nullable = false)
private Integer id;
```

I cannot change it this way, since my App will run both on MS SQL and ORACLE, and the latter does not support auto incremented columns.

As far as I know the AUTO type should use the auto increment behaviour if the underlying database has support to it, so I don't know why is not working.

UPDATE:

It took me some time but I was able to understand exactly what is going on.

I am working with legacy databases with the following behaviours:

- MSSQL: id generation uses table IDENTITY
- ORACLE: id generation uses a trigger. The trigger queries and updates a custom table where all the "next ids" are stored. This table is called SEQ.

Here is the outcome of using some id generation strategies:

- AUTO: does not work in MSSQL, as explained above
- IDENTITY: works in MSSQL but is not supported by Oracle
- "native": works in MSSQL but fails in ORACLE. It fails because Hibernate activates its default sequence strategy, which uses hibernate_sequences.nextval. Since this is a legacy application the values from the SEQ table (mentioned above) and the *hibernate_sequences*  are not synchronized (SEQ's value for that particular table is at 6120, and hibernate_sequences' is at 1, which is expected since it was not used until now).

So what I need to figure out is a way to configure that entity to:

- Use MSSQL Identity feature 
  OR
- When using Oracle, do not automatically set any value to the ID variable and leave everything up to the pre-existing trigger

This can cause me serious issues on Oracle when I need to insert entities that depend on the main entity (via foreign key), because  Hibernate won't know which ID value was generated by the "external" trigger.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem and found this [information](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6881) (deeper explained in [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.3/html/Migration_Guide/Preserve_the_Existing_Behavior_of_the_Hibernate_Identity_Auto_Generated_Value1.html)).

Adding this property into my persistence.xml file fixed the issue:

```
<property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false" />
```

Comment: This did not work for me. Hibernate still wants it's freaking 'hibernate_sequence' table .. Drives me nuts

Comment: @sashok_bg What Application Server are you using? I've tested it with Wildfly-8.2.1.Final

Comment: Worked great for me. Thanks. Using Wildfly 10

Answer (score 6):

Orcale 12c supports IDENTITY and SQL SERVER 2012 supports SEQUENCES. I believe a [SEQUENCE is always a better choice than an IDENTITY](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-identity-sequence-and-table-sequence-generator/). IDENTITY disables batching and SEQUENCES allow you to provide optimizers, such as the [pooled-lo optimization strategy](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-hidden-gem-the-pooled-lo-optimizer/).

This is how the actual identifier generator is chosen for the configured GenerationType value:

```
switch ( generatorEnum ) {
    case IDENTITY:
        return "identity";
    case AUTO:
        return useNewGeneratorMappings
                ? org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.class.getName()
                : "native";
    case TABLE:
        return useNewGeneratorMappings
                ? org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator.class.getName()
                : MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator.class.getName();
    case SEQUENCE:
        return useNewGeneratorMappings
                ? org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.class.getName()
                : "seqhilo";
}
```

- If you use the [new identifier generators](http://vladmihalcea.com/from-jpa-to-hibernates-legacy-and-enhanced-identifier-generators/):

  properties.put("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", "true");

  The AUTO will actually use a SequenceStyleGenerator and where the database doesn't support sequences, you end up using a TABLE generator instead (which is a portable solution but it's less efficient than IDENTITY or SEQUENCE).
- If you use the legacy identifier generators, you then end up with the "native" generation strategy, meaning:

  ```
  public Class getNativeIdentifierGeneratorClass() {
      if ( supportsIdentityColumns() ) {
          return IdentityGenerator.class;
      }
      else if ( supportsSequences() ) {
          return SequenceGenerator.class;
      }
      else {
          return TableHiLoGenerator.class;
      }
  }
  ```

If a new Oracle12gDialect is going to be added and it will support IDENTITY, then AUTO might switch to IDENTITY rather than SEQUENCE, possibly breaking your current expectations. Currently there is no such dialect available so on Oracle you have SEQUENCE and in MSSQL you have IDENTITY.

**Conclusion:**

Try it like this:

```
 @Id
 @GenericGenerator(name = "native_generator", strategy = "native")
 @GeneratedValue(generator = "native_generator")
 private Long id;
```

- make the id a Long instead of Integer, and you can let the HBMDDL handle the primary key column type.
- force Hibernate to use the "native" generator

If your legacy system uses a table for generating sequence values and there was no hilo optimization ever used you can use a table identifier generator:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "table", strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
@TableGenerator(name = "table", allocationSize = 1
)
private Long id;
```

You can also use the JPA table generator, just make sure you configure the right optimizer. For more info check my [Hibernate tutorial](http://vladmihalcea.com/tutorials/hibernate/)

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I couldn't derive a proper answer to my question. How can I instruct hibernate to use SQL Server IDENTITY strategy when supported and, when not supported, fall back to SEQUENCE, TABLE, or whatever strategy the underlying database supports?

Comment: Are you using MSSQL 12?

Comment: Check my updated response, the "Conclusion" section.

Comment: thanks again Vlad. That worked on SQL Server 2008 R2. I cannot test it on Oracle DB at the moment, but I have to be sure that it will work on it as well. Do you confirm that?

Comment: It should work on oracle too, only that it will the hibernate_sequence. You should not rely on hbmddl for evolving your schema. Use flywaydb or liquibase and incremental scripts. This way you can customize the Oracle db sequence nicely. This generic generator can take parameters, so you can customize the schema name for Oracle too

Comment: Nice Vlad, we're getting there! I'm using Flyway (awesome tool!) for schema update, thanks for the tip. Just one single last question: how do I instruct `@GenericGenerator` to use a specific table for storing the id values (I'm working with a legacy system, so that table already exists). The [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.4/api/org/hibernate/annotations/GenericGenerator.html#parameters()) are really poor on that subject

Comment: Check my updated response. You can set a table generator. Hibernate has many of them, both a non hilo legacy, a hilo one, a multi sequence per table with hilo and a new enhanced one taking configurable' optimizers.

Comment: Sorry if I couldn't make myself clear. The current system behaviour is: IDENTITY column in SQL Server and TABLE generator in Oracle DB. I need a mapping that works for both. So I need to somehow mix GenericGenerator with TableGenerator. The second mapping in your conclusion will use TableGenerator for both SQL Server and Oracle. (sorry if this discussion is getting too long, we may use the chat if you prefer, anyways thank you for your time.)

Comment: You need to write your own Hibernate IdentifierGenerator and switch from IDENTITY to TABLE. If the db doesn't support identity you switch to table. You can use the GenericGenerator parameters to customize your custom generator, to configure the table generator properties. Internally your custom generator could simply instantiate the legacy identity and table generator and just simply delegate the generation to one or the other, depending on your current dialect in use.

Comment: All right I'll have a look at this solution and post the result here. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the late update. The solution that uses "native_generator" works well for MSSQL 2008R2, but it does not work in Oracle. I get a "duplicate PK" error.

Comment: You need to debug it then, because it should work according to the docs.

Comment: Use of GenericGenerator worked for me, however for specifying the sequence had to use below @GenericGenerator(name = "my_seq", strategy = "native", parameters = {
 @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "my_real_seq")
})

Answer (score 0):

because

`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)`

use `SequenceStyleGenerator` by default in earlier versions

you have to look at this https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11014