# Migrating Hibernate 3 to 5: relation hibernate_sequence does not exist

Tags: java, hibernate

I am migrating an application running with Hibernate 3 to Hibernate 5.

I have a strange error:

> ERROR: relation hibernate_sequence does not exist

We are using `*.hbm.xml` mapping files and everything was working fine until I changed the Hibernate version. I mean we have a pretty straight forward mapping with ID column and DB sequence generator and still Hibernate wasn't able to pick the correct config.

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.boyan.MyClass" table="my_class">
       <id name="id" type="long">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="sequence">
               <param name="sequence">my_class_seq</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
...
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I started digging in the Hibernate code and saw that `SequenceGenerator` is deprecated and the new versions use `SequenceStyleGenerator`. I was very confused when I noticed that in the new version the property telling which is the sequence name is changed from `sequence` to `sequence_name`. So finally when I changed:

```
<param name="sequence">my_class_seq</param>
```

to:

```
<param name="sequence_name">my_class_seq</param>
```

everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

I bumped in to the same problem and I was using annotations. Solution was the accepted answer [JPA GenerationType.AUTO not considering column with auto increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047226/jpa-generationtype-auto-not-considering-column-with-auto-increment). If using annotations following should be used.

```
@GenericGenerator(name = "my_seq", strategy = "native", parameters = {
    @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "mydb_seq")
})
```