# ERROR: relation "hibernate_sequence" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I do not want to use autoincrement id. I have this table in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE public.project
(
    id character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    number bigint NOT NULL,
    state character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT project_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

And I have this model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
public class Project {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private String id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "number")
private BigInteger number;

@Column(name = "state")
private String state;
```

I want to use simple ID I do not want to use autoincrement and hibernate_sequence, and do not understand where I wrong.

And I have error:
 `ERROR 11088 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: relation "hibernate_sequence" does not exist`

Comment: Do you have anywhere in the model annotation @GeneratedValue?

Comment: No, I do not have, but before I had and I removed.

Comment: do you have any serial data type on postgresql ? because hibernate will generate sequence for this type that because you can take this error

Comment: And after removing you did a full build?

Comment: Yes, I have much serial data type in other tables. If I understand good.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migrating Hibernate 3 to 5: relation hibernate\_sequence does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35230317/migrating-hibernate-3-to-5-relation-hibernate-sequence-does-not-exist)

Comment: Not, this is not the same.

Answer (score 2):

In our entity you should use  `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` on your id especially if your table will autoincrement id.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false` in your `application.properties` file.

Answer (score -1):

Run:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE hibernate_sequence START 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case I could solve the problem by upgrading the postgres driver to a more recent version which seems to work with different (older) postgres versions as well. (updated version in build.gradle):

```
implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.18'
```