# REST to return content after POST on Java service

Tags: java, rest, jpa, netbeans, jersey

New users are created with the `POST` method, and after this the database will attach it an unique `ID`, which is necessary to create a token.

The only way to create a token, is after the process of user creation. I query it from the database and now it should have `ID` on it, but I can't figure how to do that.

Is there any way to retrieve the entity from database right after creating it?

If looked at this similar question, but couldn't find an answer: [Is it ok by REST to return content after POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829875/is-it-ok-by-rest-to-return-content-after-post)

```
@POST
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response create(@QueryParam("email") String email, @QueryParam("username") String userName, @QueryParam("password") String password) {
        if (TextUtil.isEmpty(userName) || TextUtil.isEmpty(password) || TextUtil.isEmpty(email)) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        } else {
            User newUser = new User();
            newUser.setEmail(email);
            newUser.setUsername(userName);
            newUser.setPass(password);
            super.create(newUser); //ths line create user in database
            String id = newUser.getUid() + ""; //the newUser has no id yet so it is null but I want this id from database
            return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity("id: " + id).build(); 
        }   
    }
```

Create super.method

```
public void create(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }
```

I generate REST api using this tutorial
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html

Comment: please add super.create() method listing

Comment: I have eddited my question. Thank you

Comment: ```
super.create(newUser);
super.getEntityManager().flush();
super.getEntityManager().find(User.class, newUser.getUId())
```

Comment: Make your create function return the user instead of void. In your method you would then create the user and then get it and return it.

Comment: note that newUser.getUd() is null because the id is only created in database. I use auto increment id in database

Comment: the problem is that I can not get the user cause' I do not have its id

Comment: Use the code in my previous comment to sync the EntityManager with the database.

Comment: getUId return null because the id is only created in my database

Answer (score 0):

```
getEntityManager().persist(entity);
```

Set the id of the entity by calling `entity.setId(...)`.

Comment: I set id in database by using auto increment. How can I set id by code? I cannot set it mannually right?

Answer (score 0):

I my comments I show how to sync EntityManager. Maybe you should write a better `create` method:

```
public <T> T create(T t) throws Exception {

        try {
            entityManager.persist(t);
            entityManager.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            entityManager.clear();
        }

        return t;
    }
```

And then

```
newUser = super.create(newUser);
```

Comment: the newUser does not have an Id because the id is only created in database

Comment: When `entityManager.flush();` is called, all changes are written to the database and the Ids defined in JPA are generated. How do you generate the UId field of User?

Comment: I generate it in database by using auto increment. If id is null then it auto generates an id for my user. How should I generate id? I use mySQL

Comment: UId field or getter should have `@Id` and `@Autogenerated` annotations, look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102449/how-to-annotate-mysql-autoincrement-field-with-jpa-annotations or here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047226/jpa-generationtype-auto-not-considering-column-with-auto-increment for more details

Comment: Yes I had it. Look at my code above and you can see I have getUId but it is null (in the database it is not null but in newUser object it is null). Thats my problem